# SQL 2008 geography & geometry - which to use?

Tags: sql-server-2008, geometry, geospatial, geography

I'm creating a Google map mashup and am using SQL 2008.

I will have a large number of points on the earth and will want to perform various calculations on them in SQL - such as selecting all points contained within a particular polygone, or select all points within 10km of XY.

I have never used and SQL spatial features before. Should I use the `geography` or the `geometry` datatype for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Geography is the type that is intended for plotting points on the earth.

If you have a table that stores Google Maps points like this:

```
CREATE TABLE geo_locations (
    location_id       uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL,
    position_point    geography         NOT NULL
);
```

then you could fill points in it with this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_AddPoint
    @latitude     decimal(9,6),
    @longitude    decimal(9,6),
    @altitude     smallInt
AS

DECLARE @point     geography = NULL;

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @point = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CONVERT(varchar(15), @longitude) + ' ' + 
                                                       CONVERT(varchar(15), @latitude) + ' ' + 
                                                       CONVERT(varchar(10), @altitude) + ')', 4326)

    INSERT INTO geo_locations
    (
        location_id, 
        position_point
    )
    VALUES 
    (
        NEWID(),
        @point
    );

END
```

Then if you want to query for the latitude, longitude and altitude, simply use the following query format:

```
SELECT
    geo_locations.position_point.Lat  AS latitude,
    geo_locations.position_point.Long AS longitude,
    geo_locations.position_point.Z    AS altitude
FROM
    geo_locations;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can follow the answer given in [PostGIS](http://www.postgis.org) FAQ

[I'm all confused. Which data store should I use geometry or geography?](http://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_FAQ.html#idp6582176)

> Short Answer: geography is a new data
>   type that supports long range
>   distances measurements. If you use
>   geography -- you don't need to learn
>   much about planar coordinate systems.
>   Geography is generally best if all you
>   care about is measuring distances and
>   lengths and you have data from all
>   over the world. Geometry datatype is
>   an older data type that has many
>   functions supporting it and enjoys
>   great support from third party tools.
>   Its best if you are pretty comfortable
>   with spatial reference systems or you
>   are dealing with localized data where
>   all your data fits in a single spatial
>   reference system (SRID), or you need
>   to do a lot of spatial processing.
>   Refer to Section 8.8, “PostGIS
>   Function Support Matrix” to see what
>   is currently supported and what is
>   not.

The geometry and geography types in both databases, PostGIS and SQL Server, follow the same concept, so the answer given in the PostGIS FAQ is applicable to your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you want the geography type since it accounts for the curvature of the earth. Geometry is more for a "flat" view of things. Check out this article for more info
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1847